# Managing and loading data content in Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I am curious to know how data is managed in news paper app.

I installed Times of India news paper app. Size of apk file is too small nearly 3-4 MB.

Does it load news content for various categories from server?

Initially I thought pdf file for each news content would be updated on server, and there would be trigger on insert which notify user about the new updates on news.

But I think loading pdf file for each will grow local data very high?

Can someone please clear what is correct approach for this sort of app?

Answer (score 0):

The Times of India app, like many similar apps, uses a Webservice to retrieve the information. Specifically, it connects to **timesofindia.indiatimes.com** and receives a JSON-type response with all the headlines (basically a "tree" of textual information), which it then formats to look like it looks on the app. It can then ask the server again for the full content of an article by sending a similar request with the article's unique ID.

This is common for many apps who depend on live online content. There's no PDF involved or anything, basically text which is then formatted by the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the app you are talking about, but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't download pdf files for the news.

It is more likely that the app sends a request to a server when it is loading and the server responses with articles in JSON or XML format. 
The contents are parsed then and temporarily cached. What the user sees when reading an article is just a layout (with text views, image views, etc..) filled with these cached contents.

Comment: I dealt with text data using json. can I send image also in similar manner

Comment: No, you have to pull binary files in a different way (as far as I know). I'd just pass the file name / location of the image in json and download it then.

Answer (score 0):

All kind of this type of app(except those written by newbies) are using JSON format to transfer data between client and server app.

Answer (score 0):

*Size of apk file is too small nearly 3-4 MB.*

These apps do not save any news data inside the apk file itself.

*Does it load news content for various categories from server?*

Absolutely yes.

*Can someone please clear what is correct approach for this sort of app?*

The main purpose is to minimize HTTP communication as the wifi consumes battery like hell. so reduce the HTTP calls by acquiring larger data per request and sending requests rarely. most of news applications send one initial request to load all the highlights and display detailed news only when you select one. some of them load popular news content as well to be ready just in case you will open it. sometimes they store the news locally so even when the internet is disconnected you can access some older news. in this case plain txt files/shared preferences can be appropriate for storing the news content.